# Reflection to hierarchy of type

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Let's consider following example.

```
 public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Department Department { get; set; }
    }

    public class Department 
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
    }

    public class Company
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Above Usage is like.

```
User user = new User();
user.Department = new Department();
user.Department.Company = new Company();
```

There is one function.

```
public static void Print(Company company)
        {
            // Want to get information from companyType about it's declaring or parent type.
            // Like Company -> Department -> User 
            Console.WriteLine(company.Name);
        }
```

Now if I pass company that belong nested to the User Type, I need hierarchy from that like

```
Company -> Department -> User
```

It is possible that Company may present at other level in some other type so at that time that heirarchy needs to display. For example if It is present Order -> OrderDetail -> Product -> Company at that time different hierarchy needs to display.

Note: If I have entire type present then it is easy to get down but I want to go upward upto the type.

Comment: Suggestion, why not initialize your props for example `public Department Department { get; set; } = new();` and `public Company Company { get; set; } new();` etc, then you don't need to when constructing an instance.

Comment: How it will change. In my scenario it will come from json but that is not the case. I want when I access nested property of complex type I have to find its belonging type. Now for one level it is possible with DeclaringType. e.g User has Department as property so if I get property type info then I get declaring type which is User. Now if I go bit down Department and Check Company property Declaring type then I get Deparment but from here I also want to find that it belong to which parent type. In my case it may possible same Department type present in two different parent type.

Comment: The information simply isn't available in a `Company` instance, so you can't get it there. You could add it (by having an `object` property that links to the parent) or you could implement the hierarchy explicitly, by storing the relationships in a different class and looking up the instances there (i.e. `MyHierarchy.GetParentTypeOf(thisParticularCompany)`). Obviously it will always remain simpler to be able to traverse the hierarchy in order, that is, not requiring that we have to look up the parent of a `Company` but always starting from the parent.

Comment: You could enumerate all the types in all loaded assemblies to create a property-type to owner type lookup table. But that sounds rather horrible to me. Why would you want to do this? It sounds like a X/Y problem.

Comment: an object does not know anything about its hirarchy unless you provide that knowledge to the object. So it's up to you to provide the parent to the children as well.

Comment: I agree with you that object itself does not have info so it is not possible to get it. I am using Blazor and its FieldIdentifier has model and field but not property info so when same class belong to different parent I need to validate differently based on dynamic schema from DB. Even if I maintain heirachy separately when I only have object I have to traverse to get upto that object.  if you want then I can add blazor context but situation will remain same.

Comment: You're trying to solve a problem that is unsolvable in your current model, so you'll have to change the model one way or another. If you can't do so by augmenting instances you could, for example, artificially split `Company` into `DepartmentCompany` and `ProductCompany` (these could still inherit from a base class, as long as only the specific classes are used to declare properties) so there is only one "path" for each type.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That alternative is last option in which I restrict one model class only use in one heirarchy so there is only one option possible. Thanks for information though.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.Name = "Tom Hanks";
        user.Department = new Department();
        user.Department.Company = new Company(user);

        user.Department.Company.Name = "Company GMH";
        Print(user.Department.Company);
    }

    public static void Print(Company company)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(company.User.Name);
    }
}


public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}

public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public Company(User user)
    {
        this.User = user;
    }
}
```